# Binary XML file line #80 example/my_fragment: Error inflating class com.google.android.material.search.SearchBar

Tags: android, kotlin, material-ui, searchbar

I'm trying to implement new `SearchBar` from material 3. I'm using this page:

https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/components/Search.md#putting-it-all-together

My XML file looks like this:

```xml
    androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true">
    
        <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/appbar"
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.AppBarLayout.Surface"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:elevation="0dp">
    
            <com.google.android.material.search.SearchBar
                android:id="@+id/scheme_search_bar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:navigationIcon="@drawable/ic_back"
                app:forceDefaultNavigationOnClickListener="true"
                android:minHeight="48dp" />
    
        </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>
    
        <com.google.android.material.search.SearchView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:hint="Введите схему"
            app:layout_anchor="@id/scheme_search_bar">
    
            <!-- Results of search should be here -->
            <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    
        </com.google.android.material.search.SearchView>
    
        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">
    
            <!-- Recycler View of a main screen content here -->
    
        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
    
    </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

In my fragment I have standard binding:

```
private val binding by lazy(LazyThreadSafetyMode.NONE) { FragmentWaterBinding.inflate(layoutInflater) }
```

at the top of the class and:

```
override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) = binding.root
```

When I'm running my app I'm getting crash:

> android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #80 in
> example/my_fragment: Binary XML file line #80 in example/my_fragment:
> Error inflating class com.google.android.material.search.SearchBar
> Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #80 in example/my_fragment: Error inflating class com.google.android.material.search.SearchBar
> Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
> at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
> at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:343)
> at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:881)
> at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:1033)
> at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:988)
> at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1150)
> at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1111)
> at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1153)
> at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1111)
> at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:709)
> at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:547)

And I have fresh material dependency:

```
implementation "com.google.android.material:material:1.9.0-alpha01"
```

Can you please help me to figure out what's the problem?